# Is it natural to ask someone "how did you make it?" meaning how was their trip somewhere?

Tags: phrases

Is it natural to ask someone how *did you make it**?*  meaning how was their trip somewhere? For example:

> We have been waiting you. Anyway How did you make it home?

If it's good, what would the most natural response?

Comment: How did you make it home = How did you get home; what methods?  So that is not what you intend.  If you want to know about the trip you can ask: How was your trip?

Comment: No. "Make it" in this kind of context means either "manage to get somewhere" or "Manage to be in time for something". So "make it home" means "manage to get home, against some impediment" (such as fierce winds, or drunkenness, or the car being stolen, or the bus cancelled). It doesn't match "How was your trip" in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We have been waiting you.

This is incorrect; *waiting* is (in this sense) an intransitive verb, that is, it does not take an object like “you” after it. The usual way to say this is “waiting ***for*** you.” The verb “awaiting” is also valid, though a little formal/old (“We have been awaiting you” sounds like the creepy butler at the start of a mystery film).

> Anyway

This is a natural transition, perfectly fine.

> Anyway How

This is a minor point, irrelevant if you are speaking out loud, but in writing, there needs to be punctuation between these two. Which punctuation depends on how you say it:

- “Anyway! How...” implies the “Anyway” was exuberant, possibly to the point of trying to change the subject from having been kept waiting. There would be a distinct pause between that and the “How...”
- “Anyway, how...” is the more natural phrasing, where “Anyway” is just a transition from one sentence to the next, and the comma indicates a very brief pause. Note that “how” no longer has a capital letter, because it is no longer the first word of the sentence—“Anyway, how...” is one sentence.

> How did you make it home?

This is grammatical, but it isn’t natural and it doesn’t mean what you probably meant.

This is asking the actual methods used to achieve making it home, so the answer to this question might be “I took the bus,” or maybe “I took route 37B and made the connection at Houston Street,” or whatever. In this circumstance, the more natural thing to ask is about the quality of the journey, expecting an answer like “It was nice” or “There was a crying baby on the bus that was really annoying” or whatever.

The typical wording for asking about the quality of the journey is “How was the trip?”

If you actually wanted to know the methods used in getting home, the verb “make” here suggests that there was some difficulty anticipated in getting home. So when you question it, it sounds like you didn’t expect that they *would* make it home.

Instead of “make,” “get” or “go” would be the more natural verb choice. Since you have “We have been waiting for you,” I assume that the speaker is home with the person being addressed, where that person has just arrived, so “get” is more natural of the two (if instead they called you from their home after leaving yours, “go” would be more natural).

Answer (score 1):

No.  "How did you make it?" would be asked only if there had been substantial doubt that the person COULD make it, and to inquire how.

To merely ask about the travel, you would just say, "How was the trip?"

Answer (score 1):

Your example:

> We have been waiting you. Anyway How did you make it home?

Has a few points of unnatural speech.  The first is "waiting you".  Instesd, one might say "awaiting your arrival" or "waiting for you".

Using Anyway as an interjection is fine.  It could also be a fragment.   As a fragment,  it could use a period to let the reader know.   Add an interjection,  the should be a comma and "How" would be lower case.

"How did you make it home?" Is fine, and implies that there was a real possibility that there would be troubles getting home.   Some obstacles was overcome, and you are inviting them to tell the story.

How they respond could be the focus of the story,  or they could dismiss it.

"No problem.  You worry too much."

Or...

"The strangest things happened on my easy home.  Do you have minute?  I'm still trying to make sense of it, and would love your help parsing it all. "